# Replace an empty string in a list with NaN

Tags: python, string, list

I am trying to replace an empty string in a list with a known string (say 'NAN'). I am using the following command

```
a = ['','','asdf']    
["nan" if x =='' else x for x in a]
```

The code is working, when it is used standalone, however when I am trying to employ it in my main code, it is not working. My main code is as follows:

```
data = [ ('plant_data.xlsx', 0, []),('sorg.xlsx', 1, ['','','asdf'])]#,('sloc.xlsx', 1, ['307-040N'])];


for fl in data:
    filename = fl[0];
    filename = filename[:-5];

    f = open('IC1_Results\%s.txt' %filename,'w');

    if fl[1] == 0:
        f.write("All Part Numbers exist");
        f.close()

    elif fl[1] == 1:
        a = fl[2];
        print type(a)

        ["nan" if x == '' else x for x in a]

        print fl[2],a
```

Comment: `a = ["nan" if x == '' else x for x in a]` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is working but you are simply running it without assigning the output to any location. Change the line with:

```
fl[2] = ["nan" if x == '' else x for x in a]
```

Or maybe:

```
a = ["nan" if x == '' else x for x in a]
```

Depending on where you want to store it...

Answer (score 2):

You're creating this `["nan" if x == '' else x for x in a]` list, but you're not assigning it! Your code should be like `a= ["nan" if x == '' else x for x in a]`.

Answer (score 1):

The output of [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is a new list - what you'll need to do is override your existing list (or create a new one to hold the results)

```
a = ["nan" if x == '' else x for x in a]
```

I believe that the reason you though it was working in a standalone script is that when you execute the list comprehension as-is, python will print the list to the screen, but if you want to use this new list, you'll need to save it to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option that uses the `isinstance()` method. Using `basestring` works for both plain strings and Unicode strings.

```
[np.nan if isinstance(x, basestring) else x for x in a]
```